# Remove attributes from XMLBean

Tags: java, xml, xmlbeans

Assume there's an [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) [`XmlObject`](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject.html) with attributes, how can I get selected attributes in single step?

I'm expecting like something ....

```
removeAttributes(XmlObject obj, String[] selectableAttributes){};
```

Now the above method should return me the `XMLObject` with only those attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption: the attributes that you want to remove from your `XmlObject` must be optional in the corresponding XML Schema. Under this assumption, XMLBeans provides you with a couple of useful methods: `unsetX` and `isSetX` (where `X` is your attribute name. So, we can implement a `removeAttributes` method in this way:

```
public void removeAttributes(XmlObject obj, 
    String[] removeAttributeNames)
        throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
        InvocationTargetException, SecurityException, 
        NoSuchMethodException {
    Class<?> clazz = obj.getClass();
    for (int i = 0; i < removeAttributeNames.length; i++) {
        String attrName = 
                removeAttributeNames[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
                removeAttributeNames[i].substring(1);
        String isSetMethodName = "isSet" + attrName;

        Boolean isSet = null;
        try {
            Method isSetMethod = clazz.getMethod(isSetMethodName);
            isSet = (Boolean) isSetMethod.invoke(obj, new Object[] {});
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.out.println("attribute " + removeAttributeNames[i]
                    + " is not optional");
        }

        if (isSet != null && isSet.booleanValue() == true) {
            String unsetMethodName = "unset" + attrName;
            Method unsetMethod = clazz.getMethod(unsetMethodName);
            unsetMethod.invoke(obj, new Object[] {});
        }
    }
}
```

Note 1: I have slightly modified the semantics of your method signature: the second argument (the `String[]`) is actually the list of attributes that you want to remove. I think this is more consistent with the method name (`removeAttributes`), and it also simplify things (using `unsetX` and `isSetX`).

Note 2: The reason for calling `isSetX` before calling `unsetX` is that `unsetX` would throw an `InvocationTargetException` if called when the attribute `X` is not set.

Note 3: You may want to change exception handling according to your needs.

Comment: I expected for something other than reflection, because reflection is slow. Thanks a lot for the time and answer.

Comment: I don't see any other way if you want to work with XMLBeans. Alternatively, you can work at the DOM level.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a cursor ... they are cumbersome to handle, but so is reflection.

```
public static XmlObject RemoveAllAttributes(XmlObject xo) {
    return RemoveAllofType(xo, TokenType.ATTR);
}

public static XmlObject RemoveAllofTypes(XmlObject xo, final TokenType... tts) {
    printTokens(xo);
    final XmlCursor xc = xo.newCursor();

    while (TokenType.STARTDOC == xc.currentTokenType() || TokenType.START == xc.currentTokenType()) {
        xc.toNextToken();
    }

    while (TokenType.ENDDOC != xc.currentTokenType() && TokenType.STARTDOC != xc.prevTokenType()) {
        if (ArrayUtils.contains(tts, xc.currentTokenType())) {
            xc.removeXml();
            continue;
        } 

        xc.toNextToken();
    }

    xc.dispose();

    return xo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this simple method to clean everything in the element. You can omit the **cursor.removeXmlContents** to only delete attributes. Second cursor is used to return to the initial position:

```
public static void clearElement(final XmlObject object)
{
    final XmlCursor cursor = object.newCursor();
    cursor.removeXmlContents();
    final XmlCursor start = object.newCursor();
    while (cursor.toFirstAttribute())
    {
        cursor.removeXml();
        cursor.toCursor(start);
    }
    start.dispose();
    cursor.dispose();
}
```